# Term for when sentences (or parts) are combined with "this means", "meaning", "that shows", etc.?

Tags: terminology, english, grammar

Often sentences or parts of sentences are combined with verbs or pronoun + verb. However, they don't describe something of the content of the text, they just help to bring the parts or sentences in some kind of a relation (am I right?).

Examples:

> Trees are green. **This means** they are plants.
>   Trees are green, **meaning** they are plants.
>   Trees are green, **that shows** that trees are plants.

What is the name for this type of grammar? Is that a special type of a conjunction? Or is it somehow connected to adjuncts?

Comment: You've got three very different sentences there. I don't expect anyone would give them the same label.

Comment: @curiousdannii Hm … I see … a label for just one of the examples would also help already a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Logicians make the distinction between "use" and "mention", following Quine in **Word and Object** (though I don't know that Quine was the first).  You can mention language examples, without necessarily intending to convey what would ordinarily be conveyed by saying/writing them.  In your example, "Trees are green" is both used (since it is asserted), then mentioned, when a comment is made made about the linguistic expression "trees are green".  Quine gave a famous example: "Tiny was so-called because of his size", where "Tiny" is used to refer to an individual, and mentioned, when a linguistic comment is made about the appropriateness of this name.